# How can I go to another fragment by clicking on an item in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, native

I am trying to go to another fragment(from AirportPostFragment to FinishPostFragment) by clicking on an item in a ListView.
Why does this not work?

(getActivity()) is underlined red.

Error:(61, 66) error: constructor FinishPostFragment in class FinishPostFragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: Activity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Code:

```
public class AirportPostFragment extends Fragment {

String stringsList[];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView listViewAirports;
private EditText editSearch;
Context mycontext;
XmlPullParser parser;
HashSet airport_list;
HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<String> newList = new HashSet<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_airportpost, container, false);

    listViewAirports = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_airports);
    editSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_airport);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringsList);

    listViewAirports.setAdapter(adapter);


    listViewAirports.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new FinishPostFragment(getActivity())).commit();
        }
    });




    searchAirport();

    return rootView;
}
```

This my code of FinishPostFragment:

```
public class FinishPostFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finishpost, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

---

This my code of FinishPostFragment:

```
public class FinishPostFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finishpost, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: go to your FinishPostActibity and create an constructor with activity argument

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Look at my code of FinishPostFragment below.

Comment: Where do I have to put that Daniel?

Comment: Wait, it looks like that wasn't right.  Why exactly are you trying to pass an Activity to the FinishPostFragment constructor?  It looks like you could just change it to `fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new FinishPostFragment()).commit();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you don't have a constructor for FinishPostFragment that takes an Activity.
Since you can always use `getActivity()` in a Fragment, there is no need to pass it an Activity in the constructor.

You could just change it to this:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new FinishPostFragment()).commit();
```